# How to override the subject option command in Cypress

Tags: cypress, cypress-custom-commands

Cypress says

> [options is only supported for use in Cypress.Commands.add() and not
> supported for use in Cypress.Commands.overwrite()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Arguments)

So we can't change the subject behavior when overwriting a command, and We can't add a new command with the same name as a core command ([link](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/18587)).

How can I create a `find` command with my own custom behavior and an **optional subject**.

(Note: I would take a different name, but I guess `find` and `get` are the most readable and are already part of the Cypress)

```js
// this is just an example of a custom find
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('find', (originalFn, selector, options) => {
  return cy.log('my custom find')
})

cy.get('body').find('div') // OK
cy.find('div')             // throws ERROR (I want this to be possible)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're just giving an example, but `cy.find('div')` (if it were valid syntax) is equivalent to `cy.get('div')` because `get` always searches from `<body>`.

The whole reason `find` exists is to search from a different element, a shorthand for `.within()`

```js
cy.get('my-parent-element').within(() => {
  cy.get('my-child-element')
})

// is equivalent to

cy.get('my-parent-element').find('my-child-element')
```

In the general case, if you're not using typescript you can just go ahead and add new properties to the `options` parameter and access them inside the overwrite.

If you are using typescript, you need to amend the type definition to include the new option.

Comment: Yeah, the specific question is how to overwrite `find` to make `cy.find` a valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct you cannot provide `options` to command overwrite.

But you can substitute `cy.find()` with a new command.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('find2', 
  { prevSubject: ['optional', 'window', 'document', 'element'] },
  (subject, selector, options) => {

    const originalFn = Cypress.Commands._commands.find.fn;
    if (subject) {
      return originalFn(subject, selector, options)
    } else {
      cy.get('body').then($body => {
        return originalFn($body, selector, options)
      })
    }
})
cy.find = cy.find2

cy.get('div').find('p')   // ✅ 
cy.find('div')            // ✅
```